# Acumatica:WsdlBuilder.ProcessHelpRequest(context) throws error after installing self-singed certificate

Tags: acumatica

I have two environments. 1 online, the other is local.

- online is user trial environment: win server 2016, sql server 2016,
  IIS 10.0, authorized organization signed SSL certificate. Acumatica
  18.000.0062
- Local is development environment: windows 10, sql server 2016, IIS
  10.0, Self-signed SSL certificate. Acumatica 18.000.0062

  Online environment performs properly consistently, no matter for SOAP
  service or Restful service(using oath 2.0).

However, Local worked correctly at the beginning, which means the screen-based API worked properly with the WSDL of each screen's web service be generated correctly at that time, and contract-based API responded correctly using cookies mode. Here comes the problem. After I installed self-signed certificate in order to use oath 2.0, both SOAP and rest APIs are crashed with same error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

I have digged by myself, the obvious phenomenon that indicating something went wrong is the "tools--web service" to generate WSDL. Before self-assigned certificate be installed, All screens could be generated correctly, after , all screens encountered the same error

Source File: ...\Frames\WsdlHelp.aspx.cs    Line: 9

[image]

I don't want to be misleading, but these are the details as much as I could provide. What my point is the online and local environment are almost exactly the same, online always works properly even with SSL on. So my large guess is there is something to do with the self-signed certificate. however, even after turned off the https on local IIS, the problem still exists. SO,

Is there anyone can give me some help on this headache issue?

Comment: Can you please check which version of the .net framework is installed on your machine? There has been a recent rollout of 4.7.2, so my guess is that's what you have locally (and your online probably has 4.7.1 or older).

Comment: Thanks Serg. You are right. The online is 4.7.1, while the local is 4.7.2.   So you mean the problem might be caused by the latest .net framework?  Could you teach me how can I solve it? I don't want to back to 4.7.1, unless I have to. And I don't want to update my Acumatica version currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a known issue with Acumatica and .net 4.7.2. It was fixed in 2017R2 Update 8 and 2018R1 Update 2. I'm afraid you have no choice but to either downgrade .net to 4.7.1 or upgrade Acumatica to one of those versions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kindly help. One more thing, when you are talking about 2018R1 update2, are you referring to 18.102.0048? I understand there are slightly differences in each updates. So how about I just pick the latest version currently , let's say 18.108.0016, is this also OK?

Comment: You can pick the latest version as well, it contains the fix.